# Putting a text file into an ArrayList, but if word exist it skips it

Tags: java, list, file, arraylist

I´m in a bit of a struggle here, I´m trying to add each word from a textfile to an ArrayList and every time the reader comes across the same word again it will skip it. (Makes sense?)

I don't even know where to start. I kind of know that I need one loop that adds the textfile to the ArrayList and one the checks if the word is not in the list. Any ideas?

PS: Just started with Java

This is what I've done so far, don't even know if I'm on the right path..

```
public String findWord(){
        int text = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while sc.hasNextLine()){
            wordArray[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }
            if wordArray[i].contains() {
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: share what you have tried

Comment: You have a method called `contains` which checks if an item already exists in the ArrayList. Maybe you can try with this?

Comment: Also check for HashSet. Since it doesn't allow duplicates, you can add all words into it (it'll discard duplicates automatically), then you can add the HashSet into an ArrayList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `List` (an `ArrayList` or otherwise) is not the best data structure to use; a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is better. In pseudo code:

- define a Set
- for each word

  - if adding to the set returns `false`, skip it
  - else do whatever do want to do with the (first time encountered) word

The [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) method of `Set` returns `true` if the set changed as a result of the call, which only happens if the word isn't already in the set, because sets disallow duplicates.

Comment: @jonas np. This is also has O(n) [time complexity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), which is as fast as possible for the task.

Answer (score 0):

I once made a similar program, it read through a textfile and counted how many times a word came up. 
Id start with importing a scanner, as well as a file system(this needs to be at the top of the java class)

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

then you can make file, as well as a scanner reading from this file, make sure to adjsut the path to the file accordingly. The new Printstream is not necessary but when dealing with a big amount of data i dont like to overflow the console.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file=new File("E:/Youtube analytics/input/input.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file); //will read from the file above
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("E:/Youtube      analytics/output/output.txt"));
    System.setOut(out);     
}
```

after this you can use scanner.next() to get the next word so you would write something like this:

```
String[] array=new String[MaxAmountOfWords];//this will make an array
int numberOfWords=0;  
String currentWord="";

while(scanner.hasNext()){
  currentWord=scanner.next();

  if(isNotInArray(currentWord))
  {
      array[numberOfWords]=currentWord
  }
  numberOfWords++;
}
```

If you dont understand any of this or need further guidence to progress, let me know. It is hard to help you if we dont exactly know where you are at...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public List<String> getAllWords(String filePath){    
        String line;
        List<String> allWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)));
        //read each line of the file
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //get each word in the line
            for(String word: line.split("(\\w)+"))
                //validate if the current word is not empty
                if(!word.isEmpty())
                    if(!allWords.contains(word))
                        allWords.add(word);
            }
        }
        return allWords;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use a Set. But if you still want to use a List, here goes:

Suppose the file has the following data:

```
Hi how are you
I am Hardi
Who are you
```

Code will be:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Get the file.
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/hdinesh/Desktop/samples.txt");

    //Construct BufferedReader from InputStreamReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    String line = null;
    // Loop through each line in the file
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Regex for finding just the words
        String[] strArray = line.split("[ ]");
        for (int i = 0; i< strArray.length; i++) {
            if (!list.contains(strArray[i])) {
                list.add(strArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    br.close();

    System.out.println(list.toString());
```

If your text file has sentences with special characters, you will have to write a regex for that.